# What is the right way to return object created inside a function in JS,

Tags: javascript

I can return object from function in two ways:

Way 1:

```
function f() {
  const obj = {
    a: 1,
    state: true
  }

  return obj 
}
```

Way 2:

```
function f() {
  const obj = {
    a: 1,
    state: true
  }

  return {...obj} 
}
```

What is the right way to do it from point of view memory consumption? What is the best practice?

Comment: What is the point of doing `return {...obj}`. You are just creating a shallow copy

Comment: Number 1. Although, I am not sure why memory consumption would be a problem with either of these. I'd expect memory problems to be deeply nested in logic, not just returning objects.

Comment: Yes, I create the copy.

Comment: @GregoryKafanov "*Yes, I create the copy.*" what takes more memory 1 thing or 2 things? Also, why make a copy if the original is just discarded anyway?

Comment: i thought that that there is some sort of closure.

Comment: Closure over what? Closures relate to *functions* with *variables outside the functions*. See [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102)

Comment: So as I understand it right  Way 2 is excessive.